# xaml - change StandardStyles programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am working on a Windows 8 App using xaml/c#.
I need to change the `PageHeaderTextStyle` (defined in StandardStyles.xaml).

This is my `PageHeaderTextStyle` definition:

```
<Style x:Key="PageHeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,30,40"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

How would you change the `Foreground` Attribute programmatically to "Black"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need to change it programmatically?

You can load the style normally by including code like the below in your XAML.  You can extend the existing PageHeaderTextStyle definition by changing the "BasedOn" property.  Now "myPageHeaderTextStyle" will be exactly like PageHeaderTextStyle, only with the changes you specify.

```
<Style x:Key="myPageHeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

If you do need to change it programmatically, you can use [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.setvalue.aspx) on the [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style.aspx) class (which is what your "myPageHeaderTextStyle" object is).

Comment: Thank you for your qualified answer.

Comment: Just a little explanation why I need to do this:

I want to build an App similar to the Bing Travel App, which is preinstalled on Windows 8. Within this App you have a fixed Header and a big image on the left side of a page. As the header is over the image, the headerText-color is white. If the user moves horizontally to the right and as soon as the headerText moves off the image, the headerText-color changes (to assure contrast).

I would like to "rebuild" this effect, and the only solution I see is programmatically changing Styles. If there is an "easier" solution I'd be happy!